# Show that for a sequence $p_{n}$ of real numbers, $\limsup p_{n} < +∞$ iff $p_{n}$ is bounded above.

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, limits

Show that for a sequence ${p_{n}}$ of real numbers, $\limsup {p_{n}} < +∞$ iff ${p_{n}}$ is bounded above.

My Partial Proof:

$\Leftarrow$ Given ${p_{n}}$ is bounded above, prove $\limsup {p_{n}} < +∞$

Since ${p_{n}}$ is bounded above, then $|{p_{n}}|\leq M$ $\forall n\in \Bbb N$ and for some $M\in \Bbb R$.

$a_{n}:=\{{{p_{n}}, {p_{n+1}}, {p_{n+2}},\ldots}\}$ and $A_{n}:= \sup a_{n}$.
Clearly $A_{n}\leq M$. This is valid since if $\sup a_{n}>M$, then this implies that $\exists p_{n}\in a_{n}$ such that $\sup a_{n}\geq p_{n}>M$ by Archimedean property of Reals. Hence $\limsup {p_{n}} < +∞$. Done

$\Rightarrow$ Given $\limsup {p_{n}} < +∞$

Then, $\exists N\in \Bbb N$ such that $\forall n\geq N$, ${p_{n}} < +∞$ . Let $\limsup {p_{n}}=M < +∞$.

So, $\forall n\geq N, |{p_{n}}|\leq M$.

This shows that the points in the $n^{th}$ tail of the sequence are bounded. How do I extend it for the sequence as a whole. I know my proof is a little verbose and some things may be unnecessary. I am a beginner at writing proofs, can anyone please complete the proof succinctly?

Comment: How did you define $\limsup$? Infimum of the suprema of tails? Then you should be able to trivialize "$\Leftarrow$" - For your "$\Rightarrow$" part: Conlcuding that "$\exists N\in\mathbb N$ such that $\forall n\ge N$, $p_n<+\infty$" is nonsense because the $p_n$ are real numbers and hence $<+\infty$ to begin with. And you cannot conclude thet $\forall n\ge N, |p_n|\le M:=\limsup p_n$. (Just think of $p_n=\frac1n$ with $M=0$) - (But I know that what you are after is the right idea)

Comment: @Hagen: Thanks. Can you formalize => part please?